# Print all unique integer partitions given an integer as input

Tags: algorithm, recursion, numbers, decomposition, partition-problem

I was solving a programming exercise and came across a problem over which I am not able to satisfactorily find a solution.
The problem goes as follows:

```
Print all unique integer partitions given an integer as input.
Integer partition is a way of writing n as a sum of positive integers.
```

for ex:
    Input=4
then output should be 
    Output=

```
  1 1 1 1
  1 1 2
  2 2
  1 3
  4
```

How should I think about solving this problem?
I was wondering about using recursion. Can anyone provide me an algorithm for this question?
Or a hint towards solution.
any explanation for such kind of problems is welcome.
(I am a beginner in programming world)
Thank you!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would approach it this way:

First, generalize the problem. You can define a function

```
printPartitions(int target, int maxValue, string suffix)
```

with the specification:

> Print all integer partitions of target, followed by suffix, such that each value in the partition is at most maxValue

Note that there is always at least 1 solution (provided both target and maxValue are positive), which is all 1s.

---

You can use this method recursively. So lets first think about the base case:

```
printPartitions(0, maxValue, suffix)
```

should simply print `suffix`.

---

If `target` is not `0`, you have to options: either use `maxValue` or not (if `maxValue > target` there is only one option: don't use it). If you don't use it, you should lower `maxValue` by `1`.

That is:

```
if (maxValue <= target)
    printPartitions(target-maxValue, maxValue, maxValue + suffix);
if (maxValue > 1)
    printPartitions(target, maxValue-1, suffix);
```

---

Combining this all leads to a relatively simple method (coded in Java here and I reordered the statements a little to obtain the very same order as you described):

```
void printPartitions(int target, int maxValue, String suffix) {
    if (target == 0)
        System.out.println(suffix);
    else {
        if (maxValue > 1)
            printPartitions(target, maxValue-1, suffix);
        if (maxValue <= target)
            printPartitions(target-maxValue, maxValue, maxValue + " " + suffix);
    }
}
```

You can simply call this as

```
printPartitions(4, 4, "");
```

which outputs

```
1 1 1 1 
1 1 2 
2 2 
1 3 
4
```

---

You can also choose to first create a list of all solutions and only print afterwards, like this:

```js
function createPartitions(target, maxValue, suffix, partitions) {
  if (target == 0) {
    partitions.push(suffix);
  } else {
    if (maxValue > 1)
      createPartitions(target, maxValue-1, suffix, partitions);
    if (maxValue <= target)
      createPartitions(target-maxValue, maxValue, [maxValue, ...suffix], partitions);
  }
}

const partitions = [];
createPartitions(4, 4, [], partitions);
console.log(partitions);
```

Comment: How to work around this method to fill `List<int[]> partitions = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: @Eftekhari 1) change the type of `suffix` from `String` to `int[]`, 2) change `maxValue + " " suffix` to something adding `maxValue` to the front of `suffix`, 3) add a function parameter `List<int[]> partitions` and pass the empty list on the initial call, 4) change `System.out.println(suffix)` to `partitions.add(suffix)`

Comment: It didn't work. Arrays are bigger than number. Would you please try it to make sure it works?

Comment: @Eftekhari I added a runnable javascript snippet to the answer now. You can do something similar in Java.

Answer (score 4):

This is loosely derived from [Heuster's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17721394/1711796).

Firstly, note that the last numbers of the output are `1,2,2,3,4`. If the last number is `2`, the 2nd last numbers are `1,2`. This tells me that it might be a good idea have a recursive function with a for-loop generating the string from the back.

The code itself is pretty straight-forward:

- Loop from 1 to `target`, prepending the variable to the suffix, subtracting it from `target` and recursing.
- Also note that each generated string is sorted (which implicitly avoids duplication of output). We get it sorted by simply passing in the last-generated number and looping no further than that number.

Code:

```
private void printPartitions(int target, int max, String suffix)
{
    if (target == 0)
       System.out.println(suffix);
    else
    {
       for (int i = 1; i <= max && i <= target; i++)
          printPartitions(target - i, i, i + " " + suffix);
    }
}
```

Caller function:

```
public void printPartitions(int target)
{
   printPartitions(target, target, "");
}
```

Comment: Yep, this way you get rid of the deep recursion and the code is even shorter :) I found the other easier to explain though :)

Comment: what is the time complexity of above solution?

Answer (score 2):

The process to enumerate the integer partitions of a number *n* is recursive. There is a single partition of 0, the empty set (). There is a single partition of 1, the set (1). There are two partitions of 2, the sets (1 1) and (2). There are three partitions of 3, the sets (1 1 1), (1 2) and (3). There are five partitions of 4, the sets (1 1 1 1), (1 1 2), (1 3), (2 2), and (4). There are seven partitions of 5, the sets (1 1 1 1 1), (1 1 1 2), (1 2 2), (1 1 3), (1 4), (2 3) and (5). And so on. In each case, the next-larger set of partitions is determined by adding each integer *x* less than or equal to *n* to all the sets formed by the partition of *n* − *x*, eliminating any duplicates.

I give code in several languages at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/05/11/partitions/). For example, here is my solution in Scheme:

```
(define (set-cons x xs)
  (if (member x xs) xs
    (cons x xs)))

(define (parts n)
  (if (zero? n) (list (list))
    (let ((xs (list)))
      (do ((x 1 (+ x 1))) ((= x n) (cons (list n) xs))
        (do ((yss (parts (- n x)) (cdr yss))) ((null? yss))
          (set! xs (set-cons (sort < (cons x (car yss))) xs)))))))

> (parts 0)
(())
> (parts 1)
((1))
> (parts 2)
((2) (1 1))
> (parts 3)
((3) (1 1 1) (1 2))
> (parts 4)
((4) (2 2) (1 1 2) (1 1 1 1) (1 3))
> (parts 5)
((5) (2 3) (1 1 3) (1 1 1 1 1) (1 1 1 2) (1 2 2) (1 4))
> (parts 6)
((6) (3 3) (2 2 2) (2 4) (1 1 4) (1 1 2 2) (1 1 1 1 2)
  ((1 1 1 1 1 1) (1 1 1 3) (1 2 3) (1 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an algorithm. let me know what you think. tested on python3

```
def partition(A):
    table = [[[1]]] + [None]*(A-1)
    for i in range(1,A):
        table[i] = [[i+1]]
        for k in range(i):
            table[i].extend([[i-k]+l for l in table[k] if i-k >= l[0]])
    return table[-1]

def print_partition(A):
    for i in reversed(partition(A)): print(*i)
```

Comment: Can this be modified to include only the partitions with distinct parts?

Comment: what do you mean by distinct parts? examples?

Comment: The partitions for 4 are [4], [3,1], [2,2] and [1,1,1,1]. But the partitions with distinct parts are [4] and [3,1], because the others contain duplicates. See the section about odd parts and distinct parts -> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: yes sure. just change `i-k >= l[0]` to `i-k > l[0]` :)

Comment: just to give you idea, my code uses dynamic programming.