# Integer partition in java store output in an array

Tags: java

I have the following code from [Print all unique integer partitions given an integer as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720072/print-all-unique-integer-partitions-given-an-integer-as-input)

```
void printPartitions(int target, int maxValue, String suffix) {
    if (target == 0)
        System.out.println(suffix);
    else {
        if (maxValue > 1)
            printPartitions(target, maxValue-1, suffix);
        if (maxValue <= target)
            printPartitions(target-maxValue, maxValue, maxValue + " " + suffix);
    }
}
```

When it calls `printPartitions(4, 4, "");` it gives the below output:

```
1 1 1 1 
1 1 2 
2 2 
1 3 
4
```

How can I get the output in an array like this:

```
[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2],[2,2],[1,3],[4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should collect your values to an array in this case. I've replaced the array with a list, for simplification of "add" operation (for an array you should maintain also indexes):

```
void printPartitions(int target, int maxValue, List<String> suffix, List<List<String>> list) {
    if (target == 0) {
        list.add(suffix);
    } else {
        if (maxValue > 1)
            printPartitions(target, maxValue-1, suffix, list);
        if (maxValue <= target) {
            List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
            tmp.add(0, String.valueOf(maxValue));
            tmp.addAll(suffix);
            printPartitions(target-maxValue, maxValue, tmp, list);
        }
    }
}

void callPrintPartitions() {
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    printPartitions(4, 4, new ArrayList<String>(), list);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3], [4]]
```